# given an undirected graph, direct the edges to make it transitive

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, recursive-algorithms

I am currently looking for an algorithm to determine whether we can direct every edge (no adding or deleting edges allowed) so that the graph is transitive (meaning that if (x,y) and (y,z) are edges then so is (x,z)).

One way to do it is to use PQ trees as I had an interaction with a professor and this is what he had to say but we are looking for a faster algorithm. When I try to do it myself, my mind keeps looping back to the PQ-tree technique. Each edge is allowed only one direction (if in the underlying undirected graph {a,b} is an edge then exactly one of (a,b) and (b,a) is an edge).

Perhaps there is one algorithm better in tense of toner complexity than the PQ-tree approach, but we can't seem to find it in literature. Do we take it that doing a PQ-tree approach is the best way?

The title of this post is the best I could do in the google search bar. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You wrote that we must convert un-directed edges into directed edges such that no adding or deleting edges is allowed. Is an old un-directed edge allowed to become ***TWO*** new directed edges, or only ***one***? For example, is the the un-directed edge $\{4, 98\}$ allowed to become two directed edges in the output: $(4, 98)$ and $(98, 4)$?

Comment: Note that un-directed graphs are ***already*** directed graphs. Suppose that a directed graph is any ordered pair $(VS, AS)$ such that $VS$ is a finite set and $AS \subseteq VS^{2}$. It is reasonable to define an ***un-directed*** graph as any directed graph (VS, AS) having the property that $\forall v, w \in VS$, if $(v, w) \in AS$ then $(w, v) \in AS$. That is, an un-directed graph is already directed. If you are working with a special set of graphs where $\forall v,w \in VS$, $(v, w)$ is **NOT** an arc or $(w, v)$ is **NOT** an arc, then can you edit the question to say so?

Comment: What do you mean by ***transitive***? In graph theory, the word ***transitive*** can mean many things. Suppose that $G$ is a graph and that $VS(G)$ denotes the vertex set of graph $G$. Saying that $G$ is ***transitive***  can mean $\forall v, x, z \in VS(G)$ if $(v, x)$ is an edge and $(x, z)$ is an edge, then $(v, z)$ is also an edge. However, saying that $G$ is transitive can also mean that $\forall v, w \in VS(G) \exists$ bijection $F$ from $VS(G)$ to $VS(G)$ such that $F(v) = w$ and $\forall x, y \in VS(G)$ $(x, y)$ is an edge if and only if $(F(x), F(y))$ is also an edge.

Comment: Please edit the question to define which specific type of ***transitivity*** you are talking about

Comment: Hi. Thanks Samuel for the heads-up. I have edited the question to specify edge directing norms as well as the transitivity.